# What's the correct method using PHP & HTML

Tags: php, html, methods

I have created many sites that requires php, html and css. They all work fine but i'm now thinking if all that time i do it in a wrong way. 
Usually, first i build the site template and styling and then i code the php. 
Then i just include the php functions etc in the HTML. 
For example take a look of a table that lists some posts (index.php):

```
        <div class="posts">
            <h1 class="content-title">New Posts</h1>
            <?php
                $rows = list_posts();
                while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rows)) {
                    echo "                                  
                        <div>
                            <img class='post-avatar' src='img/icon_newsletter.jpg'>
                            <h2 class='post-title'>".$row['post_title']."</h2>
                            <p class='post-meta'>
                                Από <a href='#'>".$row['post_user']."</a> | ".$row['post_date']." | <a class='post-views' href='viewpost.php?id=".$row['post_id']."#comments'>Comments: ".total_comments($row['post_id'])."</a>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                ".substr($row['post_body'], 0, 180)."...
                            </p>
                            <img class='post-icon-read' src='img/read.png' /> <a href='viewpost.php?id=".$row['post_id']."'>Συνέχεια άρθρου..</a>
                       </div>               
                    "; 
                }
            ?>      
        </div>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: if it works - it is the right way

Comment: I wouldn't echo html tags but only dynamic content. Too much <?php echo $variable; ?> of course but better for readablity. I suggest make your HTML templates to be html content, only use <?php .. ?> where you need to echo dynamic content.

Comment: My question is should i include the HTML inside the php code or include the php in the HTML page only where i need it.

Comment: like all coding, that's personal opinion

Comment: I would separate view and controller. View is the template and controller is the index.php file which controls the application. When I was not working with zend framework, I was creating .phtml files which I called templates, and include them in the actual index.php file after I set up all objects and variables that I need to echo in the template then echo between <?php .. ?> tags where I need as variables. It is what frameworks do in MVC concept but I learned it hard way, then I met the beauty using the framework. If you have time, I suggest starting using one or making time for that.

Comment: I think it was a good question.  I evened things out for you.  The down votes are rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is room for improvement.

Keep the HTML within the PHP.  It iss not personal opinion, there are technical reasons.

When you do this:

```
html

<?php  PHP   ?>

html

<?php      ?>

html

<?php   PHP   ?>

html
```

There is overhead within PHP when you switch back and forth between HTML mode and PHP Mode.  And it makes you look like a Word Press Hack.

---

A few things:
 - Heredoc syntax
 - Numeric Arrays
 - escape quotes

Start with the basic template:

```
echo <<<EOT
     // Top of page
EOT;

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rows), MYSQL_NUM) {    

}
echo <<<EOT   
   // bottom of page
EOT;
```

---

The reason to use `MYSQL_NUM` is so the column values can be use without concatenation.

Instead of

```
 <a href='#'>".$row['post_user']."</a> | ".$row['post_date']." | <a class='post-views' href='viewpost.php?id=".$row['post_id']."#comments'>Comments: ".total_comments($row['post_id'])."</a>
```

you can do this:

```
$comment = total_comments($row[2]) ;
echo "<a href=\"#\">$row[0]</a>$row[1]<a class=\"post-views\" href=\"viewpost.php?id=$row[2]#comments\">Comments: $comment</a>";
```

The backslash will escape the double quotes within double quotes.    Quote marks do not need to be escaped within Heredoc.

Single dimension Numeric arrays can be used within double quotes and within Heredoc.

---

**Top of page:**

```
echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><title>Edit Rotation Diet</title>
<style type="text/css">

</style></head>
<body><div id="page">
EOT;
```

---

**Bottom of page:**

```
echo <<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[


//]]>
</script></body></html>
EOT;
```

---

Let's say the page content is a table

```
<body><div id="page"><table>
EOT;

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rows), MYSQL_NUM) {  
  echo <<<EOT

<tr>
  <td>$row[0]</td>
  <td>$row[1]</td>
  <td>$row[2]</td>
  <td>$row[3]</td>
</tr>
EOT;  
}
echo <<<EOT
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
```

Indentation of HTML along with PHP is wrong.  You should think about how the HTML is going to look when someone views the source.  View the source on most any Word Press page..  Looks like crap.

The blank line between the echo and first html gives you a line feed.

When you echo HTML like you did it ends up looking real bad when you view the source, like Word Press.

Personally, I do not like a four space indent.  Before you know it your code is hidden beyond the right border.  I use two spaces.

I think this is ugly and a waste of vertical space:

```
if($x = 1)
{
  echo '<p>one</p>';
}
else
}
  echo '<p>two</p>'
}
```

I think this is plenty clear.  Without having excessive vertical scrolling/

```
if($x = 1){
  echo '<p>one</p>';
}
else{
  echo '<p>two</p>
}
```